# Самовывоз из офиса, расположенного по адресу или расположенному

Tags: грамотная-речь, разговорная-речь

Как правильно написать: Самовывоз из офиса, расположенного по адресу или расположенному по адресу?

Answer (score 2):

Самовывоз *откуда?* **Из офиса**.
*Из какого офиса?* **Из расположенного по адресу**.